# Achievements in PHP with mysqli

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, mysqli

I've currently got two tables:

```
mems (members):  
id,  
name,  
email,  
password,  
salt,  
achievements_id

achievements:  
id,  
achievement,  
description,  
points
```

I am able to correctly display the data for a user with:

```
"SELECT * FROM achievements WHERE id IN (SELECT achievements_id FROM mems WHERE name = '$name')";
```

My question is, how do I add the achievement ID to the user so each user has their own achievement records? Currently if I use an update it just wipes over the old achievement so it only ever displays 1 record.

Say I have 2 achievements and 2 users

- User 1 achieves achievement 1, it's viewable and they have achievements_id set to 1.
- User 2 achieves achievement 1, it's viewable and they have achievements_id set to 1.

User 1 then achieves achievement 2, it's viewable but now they have achievements_id set to 2.

I have no clue how to do this. I know what I want to do, but no clue how to design the database to have each user having their own records of achievements.
I originally did it where achievements table had a member_id and I'd concat the other users ID into their, dodgy but it semi-worked.

Any help? Sorry if I am making no sense.

Comment: You have the references wrong. Your achievements table should have member_id as a field, rather than members having an achievements id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is to model a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) (many users can share the same achievement - ie. be linked to the same entitiy in the achievements table; while a single user can have multiple achievements). This is usually done using an extra table. Let's call it: `Members_Achievements_Map`.

```
CREATE TABLE Members_Achievements_Map (
   MemberID,
   AchievementID
)
```

This table would link entities from the members table to entities in the achievements table.

Comment: One user can have many achievements....one achievement can be shared by many users...just like the badges on SO

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - `Many-to-Many` in the sense that multiple users may have the same achievement. And at the same time, a single user may have multiple achievements.

Comment: deleted my comment - misunderstood the question - sorry sweety! +1 to your asnwer :-P

Comment: This was perfect. I actually just worked it out before checking back here. I created a progress table with member id and achievement id and it worked perfectly. Thank you regardless :) - Need to wait 5 mins then I can accept your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this would be to create another table to hold the users achievements.

So basically another table that looks like such:

UserAchievements:
`userID, achievementID`

That way you can join the tables like:

```
SELECT * FROM achievements a 
INNER JOIN userAchievements uA ON uA.achievementID = a.id 
INNER JOIN users u ON uA.userID = u.id
```

That will give you all the users for all the different achievements.

Hope that helps!